# how does this site have such smooth fonts via fontface?

Tags: fonts, font-face, google-webfonts

this site 
https://slack.com/
has very nice looking fonts
smooth, not jagged at all..

they are using fontface but i cannot for the life of me get my fonts to look smooth like this site

ive tried putting svg first etc as many others have suggested
but it doesnt do anything at all

they look good on safari on windows, just not chrome IE etc on windows

why oh why doesnt chrome of windows render fonts same as safari on windows?

without all these workarounds?

Comment: As tech notes: SVG fonts won't really do anything, as [svg fonts are dead](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts), only Safari still tries to use them, for weird reasons. As to "why brower A on OS B doesn't render as browser X on OS Y": mostly because text rendering is *really complicated* so browsers defer to whatever library can best do that, and those libraries are different per OS. My best guess is that slack uses properly hinted fonts (i.e. the fonts have instructions for each glyph on how to align them to a small point raster)

Comment: hmm ok, that was more info than i expected but still doest help me achieve a similar smooth look :(